# wxpython Timer Event Interval

Tags: wxpython

I am trying to write a gui application with wx python and I need to control the interval of the timer event. Here is my code currently:

```
self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.on_timer, self.timer)        
self.timer.Start(750) # start timer after a delay
```

This is the right framework but I cannot control the interval or how often the EVT_TIMER occurs. I have been trying to figure out using the wx TimerEvent class but without any luck. I feel like this should be what I need but it isn't working:

```
self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
self.timerEvent = wx.TimerEvent(self.timer.GetId(),10)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.on_timer, self.timer)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote a [tutorial on timers](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/25/wxpython-using-wx-timers/) a while back that might help you figure this out. Basically you do as you mentioned in the first code snippet. You have to Start the timer and pass it a value in milliseconds. So 1000 would = 1 second. You don't need that bit with the wx.TimerEvent. At least, I've never needed that.

Anyway, the timer event fires every 750 milliseconds in your example, or a little less than a second. I think if you machine's CPU gets pegged, it can interrupt or delay timer events, but otherwise they're very reliable.

Answer (score 3):

In addition, if you want to control how often the `EVT_TIMER` occurs, you must set up the second parameter, the boolean `oneShot`. By default, it is set to `False`, but you can specify something like `self.timer.Start(milliseconds = 750, oneShot = True)`, and the timer will still shoting untill the `self.timer.Stop()` bit appears.

All the best.