# wxPython form built on timer interval based on sqlite3 data

Tags: python, sqlite, wxpython

I am creating a simple GUI that is used to update the status of a process by coloring and adding text to the buttons in the GUI by reading a sqlite db. The form is created correctly and I'm able to update the db based on the button events, however I cannot figure out how to read these changes to the db on a regular interval and update the GUI based on these changes.

I have now added the while True and time.sleep method in my code where I believe it should be, but now that I added it the form never builds. I haven't included the product list in the example below as it is pretty lengthy. Does anyone have any idea on how to constantly update the GUI based on the sqlite values?

```
import wx
products = []

import sqlite3 as lite
import time


con = lite.connect('test2.db')

with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    ##creates table if one is not present
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Products_Settle (Name TEXT, Status TEXT, Date DATE)")
    current_date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
    current_day = current_date[0:2]
    current_month = current_date[3:5]


##if new day dump the table and create new
cur.execute("SELECT Date FROM Products_Settle")
Date = cur.fetchone()
Date = str(Date)
Date = Date[3:11]
table_month = Date[3:5]
table_day = Date[0:2]




if current_month > table_month:
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE Products_Settle")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Products_Settle(Name TEXT, Status TEXT, Date DATE)")
    ##on new day creates new table with status for all products set to U and new dat
    for i in products:
        name = i
        status = "U"
        date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Products_Settle VALUES (?, ?, ?)",  (name, status, date))

elif current_day > table_day:
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE Products_Settle")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Products_Settle(Name TEXT, Status TEXT, Date DATE)")
    ##on new day creates new table with status for all products set to U and new dat
    for i in products:
        name = i
        status = "U"
        date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Products_Settle VALUES (?, ?, ?)",  (name, status, date))

##send to database
con.commit()









class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    while True:
        def __init__(self):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Settlement Status", size=(200, 940))
            panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)










            vertical = 0
            horizontal = 0
            Prev_product = ""








            for i in products:


                with con:





                     if products.index(i) == 0:

                         Prev_product = i
                         button = wx.Button(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label=" ", pos=(horizontal, vertical), name = i)
                         sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
                         self.buildButtons(button, sizer)
                         name1 = (button.GetName(),)
                         cur = con.cursor()
                         cur.execute("SELECT Status FROM Products_Settle WHERE Name = (?)", (name1))
                         Status = cur.fetchone()
                         if '%s' % (Status) == "U":
                            button.SetLabel("U")
                            button.SetBackgroundColour('grey')
                         elif '%s' % (Status) == "P":
                            button.SetLabel("P")
                            button.SetBackgroundColour('green')
                         elif '%s' % (Status) == "R":
                            button.SetLabel("R")
                            button.SetBackgroundColour('red')



                     elif i[:2] == Prev_product[:2]:
                        shift = 75
                        horizontal += shift
                        Prev_product = i
                        button = wx.Button(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label=" ", pos=(horizontal, vertical), name = i)
                        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
                        self.buildButtons(button, sizer)
                        name1 = (button.GetName(),)
                        cur = con.cursor()
                        cur.execute("SELECT Status FROM Products_Settle WHERE Name = (?)", (name1))
                        Status = cur.fetchone()
                        if '%s' % (Status) == "U":
                            button.SetLabel("U")
                            button.SetBackgroundColour('grey')
                        elif '%s' % (Status) == "P":
                            button.SetLabel("P")
                            button.SetBackgroundColour('green')
                        elif '%s' % (Status) == "R":
                            button.SetLabel("R")
                            button.SetBackgroundColour('red')


                     else:
                        horizontal = 0
                        shift = 40
                        vertical += shift
                        Prev_product = i
                        button = wx.Button(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label=" ", pos=(horizontal, vertical), name = i)
                        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
                        self.buildButtons(button, sizer)
                        name1 = (button.GetName(),)
                        cur = con.cursor()
                        cur.execute("SELECT Status FROM Products_Settle WHERE Name = (?)", (name1))
                        Status = cur.fetchone()
                        if '%s' % (Status) == "U":
                            button.SetLabel("U")
                            button.SetBackgroundColour('grey')
                        elif '%s' % (Status) == "P":
                            button.SetLabel("P")
                            button.SetBackgroundColour('green')
                        elif '%s' % (Status) == "R":
                            button.SetLabel("R")
                            button.SetBackgroundColour('red')
        time.sleep(15)











    #----------------------------------------------------------------------

    def buildButtons(self, btn, sizer):
        """"""
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)


    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onButton(self, event):
        """
        This method is fired when its corresponding button is pressed
        """
        button = event.GetEventObject()


        ##button clicks update db Status

        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            name2 = (button.GetName(),)
            cur.execute("SELECT Status FROM Products_Settle WHERE Name = (?)", (name2))
            Status = cur.fetchone()
            if '%s' % (Status) == "U":
                cur.execute("UPDATE Products_Settle SET Status = 'P' WHERE Name = (?)", (name2))


            elif '%s' % (Status) == "P":
                cur.execute("UPDATE Products_Settle SET Status = 'R' WHERE Name = (?)", (name2))

            elif '%s' % (Status) == "R":
                cur.execute("UPDATE Products_Settle SET Status = 'U' WHERE Name = (?)", (name2))

            con.commit()


# Run the program




if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = wx.App(False)
        frame = MyForm()
        frame.Show()
        app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: This is a lot of code for a mobile user to read. Have you looked into the wxpython event timers? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486500/wxpython-timer-event-interval

Answer (score 1):

```
items = itertools.cycle(["APPLE","ORANGE","PEAR","PLUM","PLUOT","MELON","CHERRY","PEACH"])
class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,-1,"A form title")
        self.label = wx.StaticText(self,-1,"A Label That Updates")
        self.UpdateFunc(None)
    def UpdateFunc(self,event):
        self.label.SetLabel(next(items))
        # you would update your labels with values from sqlite here...
        wx.CallLater(1000,self.UpdateFunc) # schedule a new call for one second later
```

you need to update your GUI in a non-blocking way ... this is probably the easiest ... this has a minor benefit(over wx.Timer) that the second delay starts after you finish the function thus ensuring you dont interrupt yourself for ever